# cleaning setstate in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a function called getLines which tries to find out when text is going to wrap in another line it is async and it is so time-consuming
and I have an API that gives a string with a given length (query)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import getLines from "./getline"; //this function take time according to input

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState<string>("");
  const [arr, setArr] = useState<string[] | "error" | undefined>([]);
  const [time, setTime] = useState<100 | 200 | 300 | "un">("un");
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (time !== "un") {
      (async () => {
        setPending(true);
        let res = await fetch(
          `https://random-word-genrator.vercel.app/words?w=${time}`
        );
        let { response } = await res.json();
        let a = await getLines(800, response, "1.2rem", "3px");
        setArr(a);
        setText(response);
        setPending(false);
      })();
    }
  }, [time]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", gap: "1rem" }}>
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            setTime(100);
          }}
        >
          100
        </div>
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            setTime(200);
          }}
        >
          200
        </div>
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            setTime(300);
          }}
        >
          300
        </div>
      </div>
      {pending ? (
        <div>loading</div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <div>value:={text}</div>
          <div>array:={JSON.stringify(arr)}</div>
          <div>length:={text.split(" ").length}</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[video of problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17wvP_RCY9JjXW2VXCwBd1iMc3CYWT58U/view?usp=sharing)

you can see in video that when I click 100 it give me 100 words when I click to 200 it give me 200 words but when I click multiple button it gives me different length then what I last clicked
can anyone tell me how can i remove this problem?
sanboxLink:- [sendbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-kowalevski-l5q9bu?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1501) 
**recreate error by quickly clicking 300 and 100 with this order 300--quickly-->100

Comment: You don't need that `useEffect`. Just use an event handler with a state to enable/disable button.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking multiple times invokes multiple operations.  Since the operations are asynchronous, they can complete in any order.

If you don't want the user to be able to invoke multiple simultaneous operations, prevent/ignore the click when an operation is still pending.  The `pending` state value you already have seems like a reasonable way to check that.

For example, you can display "loading" instead of the "buttons" (well, clickable `div`s):

```
return (
<div>
  {pending ? (
    <div>loading</div>
   ) : (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", gap: "1rem" }}>
      <div onClick={() => { setTime(100); }} >
        100
      </div>
      <div onClick={() => { setTime(200); }} >
        200
      </div>
      <div onClick={() => { setTime(300); }} >
        300
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>value:={text}</div>
      <div>array:={JSON.stringify(arr)}</div>
      <div>length:={text.split(" ").length}</div>
    </div>
  )}
  </div>
);
```

Alternatively, you could keep the UI but just ignore the click:

```
<div onClick={() => {
  if (!pending) {
    setTime(100);
  }
}} >
  100
</div>
```

Comment: can do something without hiding 100 200 300?

Comment: @PradeepBisht: Another alternative could be to not perform the `setTime` operation (effectively ignoring the click) if there is a "pending" operation.  I've updated the answer with an example.  Overall there are a variety of things you could do, depending on the UX you want.  In every case the general point is that you just want to prevent another operation from starting while a previous one hasn't completed.

Comment: tq for your help

Comment: can you explain little bit more about what another comment is saying?@jahller

Comment: @PradeepBisht: What "other comment"?  You appear to have perhaps posted that last comment on the wrong answer?  Because it's attempting to "tag" someone who isn't in this comment thread.

Comment: someone else also comment on this question his answer seems like what I am looking for and he is not replying so if you understanding what he is saying can you please explain me?

Comment: @PradeepBisht: Personally I think the other answer of this question is drastically over-engineering an approach and will only add complexity and potential bugs.  My preference is the approach described in this answer.  If you want clarification about someone's answer then you should ask that person.